# null model fail to converge in an AICc anaysis

Tags: r

I am doing an AICc analysis with my insect biomass per hour data in R to find which of the environmental predictors I've measured influence the biomass the most. I am doing glmm with the Gamma distribution and a "log" as link function for my model competition. All my models are converging except my null model. I am still struggling to understand why this is hapenning. Does anybody have an idea? Here is my code in R:

What my data look like:

```
> str(insectnona)
'data.frame':   76 obs. of  28 variables:
 $ TIME        : Factor w/ 7 levels "2016_6","2016_7",..: 4 6 7 3 2 4 6 7 2 3 ...
 $ JULIAN      : Factor w/ 28 levels "147","148","149",..: 3 9 23 24 16 2 11 20 10 19 ...
 $ SITE        : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","3","5","12",..: 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 ...
 $ HABITAT     : Factor w/ 3 levels "C","E","F": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ TEMP_CIVIL  : num  17.8 18.9 21.1 15 16 ...
 $ BIO_ZONE    : Factor w/ 3 levels "ESSFwh3","ICHdw1",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ AGE_CLASS   : Factor w/ 3 levels "6","7","8": 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 3 3 ...
 $ RICHNESS    : int  4 9 9 9 8 6 8 8 3 2 ...
 $ ARANEAE_Btot: num  0 0.1 0.1 6.9 3.73 ...
 $ COL_Btot    : num  2152.4 66.8 88.4 6.9 80.4 ...
 $ DIP_Btot    : num  72.8 39.6 17.7 20.9 132.4 ...
 $ EPH_Btot    : num  0 0 0 10.2 0.0333 ...
 $ HEM_Btot    : num  0 0.1 18.5 0 0 ...
 $ HOM_Btot    : num  0 14.9 30 6.2 0 ...
 $ HYM_Btot    : num  40.9 65.6 36.5 38 36.7 ...
 $ LEP_Btot    : num  161 2625 696 390 869 ...
 $ NEU_Btot    : num  0 0.1 3 15.5 10.6 ...
 $ ORT_Btot    : num  0 24.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PSO_Btot    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 9.3 0 0 0 ...
 $ THY_Btot    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TRI_Btot    : num  0 0 34.5 20.3 4.4 ...
 $ BIOMASS_tot : num  2427 2837 924 515 1138 ...
 $ OTHER_Btot  : num  114 145 140 118 188 ...
 $ COL_bhr     : num  321.254 10.603 10.914 0.843 11.518 ...
 $ LEP_bhr     : num  24.1 416.7 85.9 47.7 124.5 ...
 $ BIOMASS_hr  : num  362.3 450.3 114.1 62.9 162.9 ...
 $ RICHNESS_hr : num  0.597 1.429 1.111 1.1 1.146 ...
 $ sTEMP_CIVIL : num  0.6228 0.8304 1.263 0.0796 0.2736 ...
```

My model competition:

```
modl <- list()
modl[[1]]=glmer(BIOMASS_hr~AGE_CLASS + HABITAT + (1|SITE) + (1|TIME), data=insectnona,family="Gamma"(link="log") )
modl[[2]]=glmer(BIOMASS_hr~HABITAT + (1|SITE) + (1|TIME), data=insectnona,family="Gamma"(link="log") )
modl[[3]]=glmer(BIOMASS_hr~AGE_CLASS + (1|SITE) + (1|TIME), data=insectnona,family="Gamma"(link="log") )
modl[[4]]=glmer(BIOMASS_hr~BIO_ZONE + (1|SITE) + (1|TIME), data=insectnona,family="Gamma"(link="log") )
modl[[5]]=glmer(BIOMASS_hr~sTEMP_CIVIL + (1|SITE) + (1|TIME), data=insectnona,family="Gamma"(link="log") )
modl[[6]]=glmer(BIOMASS_hr~AGE_CLASS + HABITAT + sTEMP_CIVIL + (1|SITE) + (1|TIME), data=insectnona,family="Gamma"(link="log") )
modl[[7]]=glmer(BIOMASS_hr~HABITAT + sTEMP_CIVIL + (1|SITE) + (1|TIME),data=insectnona,family="Gamma"(link="log") )
modl[[8]]=glmer(BIOMASS_hr~HABITAT + BIO_ZONE + (1|SITE) + (1|TIME),data=insectnona,family="Gamma"(link="log") )
modl[[9]]=glmer(BIOMASS_hr~AGE_CLASS + HABITAT + BIO_ZONE + (1|SITE) +(1|TIME),data=insectnona,family="Gamma"(link="log") )
modl[[10]]=glmer(BIOMASS_hr~1 + (1|SITE) + (1|TIME),data=insectnona,family="Gamma"(link="log"))
aictab(modl)
```

And then I get this warning message only for the null model (model 10):

> `Warning message: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl =
>   control$checkConv,  :   Model failed to converge with max|grad| =
>   0.0169244 (tol = 0.001, component 1)`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: have you explored the possibilities in `?lme4::convergence` ?

Comment: BTW I'm a little surprised that `family="Gamma"(link="log")` (rather than `family=Gamma(link="log")`, i.e. no quotes around `Gamma` works: is that really what you specified, or is that a transcription error?

Comment: Hi @Ben Bolker. Yes, I just made a transcription error for Gamma. I looked at `?lme4::convergence` ...there a lot of that that I've already tried.

Comment: Might not be able to answer this without a reproducible answer. If you do get similar answers with different optimizers (and with other frameworks, e.g. `glmmTMB`/Julia `MixedModels.jl` :-) ) then this is probably a false positive.

Comment: Will try that thank you.